# Invalid grant when trying to connect to google cloud sql with django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I've been following the GAE tutorial for setting up a django project to run on app engine.  I've finally gotten it to successfully run to makemigrations for my project, but I get a connection error in my google cloud sql proxy:

```
2017/06/25 15:12:07 New connection for "[MY_CONNECTION_NAME]"
2017/06/25 15:12:08 couldn't connect to "[CONNECTION_NAME]": Post 
https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project-id/instances/projectname/createEphemeral?alt=json: oauth2: cannot 
fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this, so I'll take any help???

Comment: can you post the connection string used in the django settings.py file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is an error given by the OAuth library when you are trying to authenticate using a Service Account which has been deleted, or using a credential file that corresponds to a private key which has been deleted.

How are you authenticating the Cloud SQL Proxy? If you are using the -credential_file, can you verify the associated service account still exists?